Next js 14vinstall Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.
See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error
In HTML,  cannot be a child of .
This will cause a hydration error.
please help!
I provided detailed steps and code examples to address the warnings and errors related to Chrome extensions and Next.js rendering. I expected to provide you with solutions to resolve these issues, allowing your application to function properly without errors or warnings.
